# Google URL Shorter API returning 403 with authorized API key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, url-shortener

We are developing an application and we are using google API shorter URL to reduce very long URL.

This was working fine until a week ago. The API started to return 403 Unauthorized.

The problem appeared when we switched API key. It was working fine when we were testing but failed in production.

We checked that the API keys are correct, and they are. We are testing request with postman. Credit card is also correct but we are still under the free plan, so nothing wrong with payment.

API key is not restricted, and registered for the for the Google Shorter API.
The dashboard is showing our requests but all are in error.

The request we made :

```
curl -X POST \
    'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=TheApIKeyStaNDshEre' \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
    -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{
        "longUrl": "http://example.com/foo/bar/log/url/with?params=true"
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Someting the team hasn't see is that the API key has been regerated AFTER the limit.

From google blog post :

> Starting May 30, 2018, only projects that have accessed URL Shortener APIs before today can create short links.

We missed this part when they decided to regenerate the key, and now we are locked out.

So we'll go for an hot fix to switch to firebase.

Don't regenerate your keys or you will be locked out forever.

(sorry @Ricky, we missed the part, you were right)

Answer (score 0):

Google is shutting down the service. This could be the reason if your code worked properly before.

https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/transitioning-google-url-shortener.html

Comment: No it was literraly working last week, and they are not shutting down  the API right now, we are aware and working to change it in a near future. 
Also quoting : `you can continue to use them for a period of one year, until March 30, 2019`